# History of owners of files - os.stat

Tags: python, windows

Is it possible to track a history of owners of files within Windows Explorer or is the creator and last owner retained?

I am trying to find the penultimate owner of a file not the most recent.

I have been using os.stat but it seems only the final owner is retained.

Comment: This would be wholly dependent on the file system under consideration; an API can't return what isn't stored in the first place.

Comment: Is this with reference to NTFS or FAT32?

Comment: Those are two examples of file systems, yes.

Comment: Either? Both? Neither? You tell me which file system you are using, and I (in theory) tell you whether it tracks all the owners of a file over time.

Comment: ah I'm referring to computer at work - i'm at home so couldnt say

Comment: In theory would one system type record a history? and which would that be?

Comment: In theory, *any* file system could. The point is, your question can't be answered without specifying which file system you are using (but to the best of my knowledge, most file system *don't* track this information).